# Android remove statusbar completely from phone? (all apps fullscreen)

Tags: java, android

I'm building a home replacement app for people with bad eyesight. I want to remove the statusbar completely from the phone.

I know how to remove the statusbar just on the launcher:

```
<style name="Theme" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>
```

But I don't know how to remove it from all apps. How can it be done?

Comment: I don't believe this to be possible, see https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-developers/GIq2Lao9jX4/fAbb89vdxBgJ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But I don't know how to remove it from all apps. How can it be done?

Step #1: Download the source code to Android.

Step #2: Modify the operating system to do something else with the status bar.

Step #3: Compile the source code and pour it into a ROM mod that you install on devices.

You do not have the right, from an SDK app, to hack into other apps written by other developers and change them.

Comment: I should have mentioned: without rooting the device. But I got the point